# No sound with HTML5 video player under firefox or chromium with Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, chromium, html5

under firefox, if I set youtube to use the html5 video player or if i try to watch something on vimeo, I can't hear anything, but I can hear the sound of the video if I use the flash video player on youtube.

When I play an html5 video, I can see in pulseaudio the sound stream called CubebUtils with firefox logo under the "applications" tab, and the volume is set to 100%, but I can't hear anything.
The same thing occurs with chromium: I see in pulseaudio the chromium stream, I see the video, but I can't hear anything.
I can hear the sound from any other application (vlc, system sounds, flash player, etc...)

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution!

It was not related to chromium or firefox, it was a configuration setting. In pulseaudio, sound stream from this 2 applications were configured to go to HDMI audio output, instead of built-in speakers.

As you can not change this setting for each application in the default "sound" application, I had to install pavucontrol and then I could redirect the streams correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: Thanks, with pavucontrol I could fix it. On the Playback tab, HDMI was selected by default. Changing it to "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" the sound came back.

Comment: I had to go to the "configuration" tab, then switch the "Built-in Audio" tab from "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (unplugged)" to "Off".